# Kinesis Subscribe to Shard

Tags: python, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to stream the data from Kinesis as Enhanced fan out consumer.  Below is code i am using

kinesis = Session().create_client("kinesis", region_name="us-east-1")

response = kinesis.subscribe_to_shard(ConsumerARN='Regiserd consumer ARN', ShardId=self.shard_id, StartingPosition={'Type': 'LATEST'})

When i am printing the response, it is printed as "'EventStream': ". How can i convert this eventStream to specifc data available in shards

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i was able to iterate the stream and get the actual message.